# Переместить onclick() из HTML в JS

Tags: javascript

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("blogSlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
.blog-slider__container {
  max-width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
}
.blog-slider__container .blogSlides img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */
.blog-slider__text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.blog-slider__numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.blogSlider__dots {
  text-align: center;
}
.blogSlider__dots--dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .blogSlider__dots--dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-slider__container">
  <div class="blogSlides fade">
    <div class="blog-slider__numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6i60hcgrz7yatl5/nexus-6-2770-001.jpg?raw=1">
    <div class="blog-slider__text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="blogSlides fade">
    <div class="blog-slider__numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wu9u6l53z3q6zpa/date.jpg?raw=1">
    <div class="blog-slider__text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="blogSlides fade">
    <div class="blog-slider__numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7vg753l95iv7g8/photo-bg-04.jpg?raw=1">
    <div class="blog-slider__text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Найдите ваши div кнопки по классу и прицепите к ним обработчики с вызовом функции.
Примерно это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', () => this.plusSlides(-1));
```

Comment: Только учтите, что `querySelector` вернет только самый первый найденный элемент с классов `.prev`.

Comment: Можно искать или по уникальному id, data- свойству или внутри блока blog-slider__container, чтобы избежать зацепки элементов с таким же классом.

Comment: На что должен указывать `this` чтобы это все заработало?